# Submit and change form on button click (embedded forms)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a pop-up form which displays a form initially. Upon completing the form and clicking next, it will submit that form and show another form in its place. However, with my JavaScript being "out of sync", I believe I'm not using the right approach.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal-content .hs-button").click(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var currentSection = button.parents(".section");
    var currentSectionIndex = currentSection.index();
    var headerSection = $('.steps li').eq(currentSectionIndex);
    currentSection.removeClass("is-active").next().addClass("is-active");
    headerSection.removeClass("is-active").next().addClass("is-active");

    $(".form-wrapper").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    if (currentSectionIndex === 3) {
      $(document).find(".modal-content .form-columns-2 .form-columns-1").first().addClass("is-active");
      $(document).find(".steps li").first().addClass("is-active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1900px) {
  .modal .modal-content {
    width: 50% !important;
  }
  .modal input[type=text],
  .modal input[type=email] {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  .modal textarea {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
}

.input textarea {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal .modal-content {
  background-color: #097afb;
  margin: 4% auto 15% auto;
  width: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.modal .steps {
  text-align: center;
}

.modal .steps li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.modal .imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.modal .imgcontainer h2 {
  font-size: 29px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.modal .imgcontainer p {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.modal input[type=text],
.modal input[type=email] {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  margin: 10px 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #414141;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.modal textarea {
  width: 98% !important;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #414141 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;
  resize: none;
}

.modal form span:not(.close) {
  display: none !important;
}

.modal form .actions {
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  width: 87%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.modal form .actions input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.modal .close:hover {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.hs-input,
textarea.hs-input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

textarea.hs-input {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

textarea.hs-input {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="visible" class="button-outline hero-button button-arrow" onclick="document.getElementById('modal-wrapper').style.display='block'">Click here</a>

<div id="modal-wrapper" class="modal" style="display: none;">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <form class="modal-content animate">
<div class="imgcontainer"><span onclick="document.getElementById('modal-wrapper').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close PopUp">×</span>
          <h2 style="text-align: center;">Title</h2>
          <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
          <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
          <script>
            // <![CDATA[
            hbspt.forms.create({
              portalId: "103687",
              formId: "7c124354-e1ff-411d-9245-2b214e943a90"
            });
            // ]]>
          </script>
          <div></div>
          <ul class="steps">
            <li class="is-active"><a>Step 1</a></li>
            <li>/</li>
            <li><a>Step 2</a></li>
            <li>/</li>
            <li><a>Step 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </form>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

To simplify, user clicks the button > form appears > user fills out form > Form is submitted and second form is shown.

Issues, the form itself is embedded onto the popup, so I can't alter the `fieldset` as shown in [this approach](https://codepen.io/RRoberts/full/dOjRqa/).

Form 1 embed code is shown in the fiddle. On form 1 submit, I need form 2 to appear i.e.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: "103687",
    formId: "555bd0a1-adb9-4e31-b71e-e09e4834e844"
});
</script>
```

I think my entire JS code is not "efficient". I've seen multistep forms created where it just involves a single form, but unsure how to do it with multiple forms.

Comment: solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for modal popup:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/VdKymZ

I have just used bootstrap and changed HTML

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


<div class="containers">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="steps">
        <li class="is-active">Step 1</li>
        <li>Step 2</li>
        <li>Step 3</li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-wrapper">
        <fieldset class="section is-active">
          <h3>Your Details</h3>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
          <div class="button">Next</div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="section">
          <h3>Account Type</h3>
          <div class="row cf">
            <div class="four col">
              <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" checked>
              <label for="r1">
                <h4>Designer</h4>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="four col">
              <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r2"><label for="r2">
                <h4>Developer</h4>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="four col">
              <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r3"><label for="r3">
                <h4>Project Manager</h4>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="button">Next</div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="section">
          <h3>Choose a Password</h3>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
          <input class="submit button" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="section">
          <h3>Account Created!</h3>
          <p>Your account has now been created.</p>
          <div class="button">Reset Form</div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

What's needed is the `target` option to tell hubspot where to put the form:

```
<script>
hbspt.forms.create({ 
    portalId: "103687",
    formId: "555bd0a1-adb9-4e31-b71e-e09e4834e844",
    target: "#my_form",
});
</script>
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35810817/edit)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my case to prepopulate the form from PHP output, then submit it:

```
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "na1",
    portalId: "xxx",
    formId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-291a664xxxx",
onFormReady: function($form){
$form.find('input[name="firstname"]').val('<?php echo $order->get_billing_first_name(); ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="lastname"]').val('<?php echo $order->get_billing_last_name(); ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="email"]').val('<?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="phone"]').val('<?php echo $order->get_billing_phone(); ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="company"]').val('<?php echo $pbi_agency; ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="state_province_region"]').val('<?php echo $pbi_state; ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="city"]').val('<?php echo $pbi_city; ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="build_id__"]').val('<?php echo $pbi_PNB; ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="product_model"]').val('<?php echo $product_name; ?>').change();
$form.find('input[name="pdf_link"]').val('<?php echo $pdf; ?>').change();
$form.submit();
}
  });
</script>
```

The important parts:

- using onReady to populate it
- adding in $form.submit() to submit the form after it was changed.

All of this plays out in the iframe, so it sends the output without user input.